# Как записать несколько подгружаемых скриптов в одном JS-файле?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как записать нижеследующий скрипт в файле checkout.js, чтобы потом подключать его на страницу?

```
<script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function() {
            $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");  
    });
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0) {
                $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
            }
        });
                $('.x-drop-down__list-item').click(function(){
        $('#payment_option').val($(this).children().text());
        $('#tupe').html($(this).children().html());
    });
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                        $(".x-shipping-form-row__field").click(function() {
                $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");  
    });
                $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.closest(".x-shipping-form-row__field").length == 0) {
                $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");
            }
        });
                $('.x-drop-down__list-item-shipping').click(function(){
        $('#shipping_option').val($(this).children().text());
        $('#tupe-shipping').html($(this).children().html());
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Зачем 5 раз добавлять jquery?

Comment: Так как правильно его записать в js что бы потом просто подключать этот js ?

Comment: jquery подключаете один раз , а всё что самописное выносите в отдельный файл

Comment: Вот хочу правильно вынести в отдельный файл checkout.js только не знаю как правильно в нем записать этот скрипт. Поправьте мною написанный скрипт что выше !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это код, который должен быть в checkout.js.

```
$(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function() {
  $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0) {
    $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
  }
});
$('.x-drop-down__list-item').click(function() {
  $('#payment_option').val($(this).children().text());
  $('#tupe').html($(this).children().html());
});


$(".x-shipping-form-row__field").click(function() {
  $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.closest(".x-shipping-form-row__field").length == 0) {
    $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");
  }
});
$('.x-drop-down__list-item-shipping').click(function() {
  $('#shipping_option').val($(this).children().text());
  $('#tupe-shipping').html($(this).children().html());
});
```

Если этот файл лежит на одном уровне с HTML-файлом, тогда подключаешь его так: `<script src="./checkout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, Перед этим качаешь библиотеку JQ, кладешь ее на тот же уровень, что и html, пареименовываешь ее на `jquery.js` и подключаешь ее так:
HTML:

```
<body>
  <!--...Весь твой html код-->
  <script src="./jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./checkout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю зачем вы хотите 5 раз подгрузить jQuery, но одним файлом весь ваш код можно записать так:

```
function addScript(srcUrl)
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.charset = "UTF-8";
    //Атрибут defer откладывает выполнение скрипта до тех пор, пока вся страница не будет загружена полностью.
    script.defer = false; //в данном случае не откладывает
    script.src = srcUrl;
    document.head.appendChild(script)
}

addScript('http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js');
addScript('wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');

$(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function()
{
    $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");  
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e)
{
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0)
    {
        $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
    }
});

$('.x-drop-down__list-item').click(function()
{
    $('#payment_option').val($(this).children().text());
    $('#tupe').html($(this).children().html());
});

addScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js');
addScript('http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js');
addScript('wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');

$(".x-shipping-form-row__field").click(function()
{
    $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");  
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e)
{
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.closest(".x-shipping-form-row__field").length == 0)
    {
        $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");
    }
});

$('.x-drop-down__list-item-shipping').click(function()
{
    $('#shipping_option').val($(this).children().text());
    $('#tupe-shipping').html($(this).children().html());
});
```

Comment: Теперь его просто внизу страницы <script src="checkout.js" type="text/javascript"></script> подключаю и работает верно ?

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv, да.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос закрыт!

Comment: Активировать defer через true ?

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv, если нужно, то да.

Comment: Почему-то не работает ..

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv, что не работает?

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv, вы написали script.defer = true? Если после этого не работает, то это естественно, т.к. после этого все скрипты грузятся в конце. В данном случае вам этого не нужно. Я же написал, что только в том случае true, если нужно. Поставьте false и всё заработает.

Comment: Я ниже в ответе скинул html и js. Посмотри что не так!

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv,вы же написали, что надо всё в один файл, а скрипты вверху не удалили. Их надо удалить и оставить только нижний, где все в одном. Они не работают возможно потому, что возможно в данном случае 2 раза выполняться не могут. Ещё я не понимаю зачем подгружать jQuery 5 раз? Достаточно одного раза в самом начале скрипта. Из-за этого тоже может не работать, т. к. разные версии переплетаются.

Comment: Капец, не пойму почему но не работает! Убрал весь скрипт с html. Подключил только в конце твой что ты написал. Вообще 0 ..

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv, исправьте свой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835490/ а я посмотрю что вы там исправили.

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv, в самом начале оставляете только один раз addScript('wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'); А все остальные 4 вызова функции addScript удалите.

Answer (score 0):

Внешний скрипт подключается из HTML, добавлением элемента

`<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

в низ страницы. 
В данном случае, файл main.js лежит в одной папке с html файлом.

Вам надо jquery кусок оставить, а самописную часть вынести как раз в отдельный файл.

Comment: А можно отобразить правильный ответ в скрипте ? показать что оставить внизу страницы, а что именно перенести в файл js ??

Answer (score 0):

checkout.js:

```
    function addScript(srcUrl)
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.charset = "UTF-8";
    //Атрибут defer откладывает выполнение скрипта до тех пор, пока вся страница не будет загружена полностью.
    script.defer = false; //в данном случае не откладывает
    script.src = srcUrl;
    document.head.appendChild(script)
}

addScript('wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');

$(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function()
{
    $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");  
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e)
{
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0)
    {
        $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
    }
});

$('.x-drop-down__list-item').click(function()
{
    $('#payment_option').val($(this).children().text());
    $('#tupe').html($(this).children().html());
});

$(".x-shipping-form-row__field").click(function()
{
    $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");  
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e)
{
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.closest(".x-shipping-form-row__field").length == 0)
    {
        $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");
    }
});

$('.x-drop-down__list-item-shipping').click(function()
{
    $('#shipping_option').val($(this).children().text());
    $('#tupe-shipping').html($(this).children().html());
});
```

html:

```
    <div class="of-zakaza">
  <div class="x-checkout">
    <div class="x-checkout__form-holder">
        <form class="x-order-form" method="post">
                <div class="x-order-form__content">
                    <div class="x-order-form-row">
                        <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ оплаты:</div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row__field x-order-form-row__field_pos_relative">
                            <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="payment_option">
                                <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe">Выберите способ оплаты</span><img class="arrow" src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/icons8-шеврон-вниз-16.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст"></span>

                                <input type="hidden" id="payment_option" name="payment_option" value="">

                                <ul class="x-drop-down__list  js-dropdown">
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/privatbank.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Безналичный расчет</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Наложенный платеж</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



    <div class="x-shipping-form-row">
                        <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ доставки:</div>
                        <div class="x-shipping-form-row__field x-shipping-form-row__field_pos_relative">
                            <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="shipping_option">
                                <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe-shipping">Выберите способ доставки</span><img class="arrow" src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/icons8-шеврон-вниз-16.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст"></span>

                                <input type="hidden" id="shipping_option" name="shipping_option" value="">

                                <ul class="x-drop-down__list-shipping  js-dropdown-shipping">
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item-shipping js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Новая Почта</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item-shipping js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/logo-delivery-auto.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Деливери</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

     <div data-reactroot="">
                        <div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="first-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="oblast" placeholder="Введите область (Киевская обл.)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="last-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="city" placeholder="Введите город (Киев)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="second-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="warehouse" placeholder="Введите номер отделения (#199)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-reactroot="">
                        <div>
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">ФИО получателя:</div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="first-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="firstName" placeholder="Имя" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="last-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="lastName" placeholder="Фамилия" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="second-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="secondName" placeholder="Отчество" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row">
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Email:</div>
                            <div class="x-input " data-qaid="client_email"><input type="email" class="x-input__field qa-test-email" maxlength="255" placeholder="Email" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <!-- react-empty: 53 -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- react-empty: 54 -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row">
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Телефон:</div>
                            <div class="x-input" data-qaid="client_phone"><input type="text" class="x-input__field qa-test-phone" placeholder="(093)-123-4567" value="" maxlength="20" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <!-- react-empty: 59 -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row">
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Комментарий:</div>
                            <div class="x-input"><textarea class="x-input__field" data-qaid="notes_input" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Укажите по желанию доп.инфо по заказу, пожелания, цвет и тд. товара!" rows="3"></textarea>
                                <!-- react-empty: 72 -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-prepare__total">
                            <div class="x-order-total">
                                <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_total">
                                    <div class="x-order-total__label">Всего</div>
                                    <div class="x-order-total__value"><span data-qaid="total_price">2 886 грн.</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form__accept">
                            <div class="x-order-accept"><span class="x-button x-button_width_full x-button_theme_purple" data-qaid="create_order_btn"><span class="x-button__text qa-test-create-order">Оформить заказ</span></span>
                                <div class="x-order-accept__min-order x-hidden"></div>
                                <div class="x-order-accept__min-order x-hidden"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div class="x-checkout__order-info-holder">
        <div class="x-order-prepare">
            <div class="x-order-prepare__content">
                <div class="x-order-prepare__header">
                    <div>Ваш заказ</div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-prepare__list">
                    <div class="x-order-product" data-qaid="product">
                        <div class="x-order-product__image-cell">
                            <div class="x-order-product__image-holder">
                                <img class="x-order-product__image" src="https://images.ua.prom.st/1166108104_w100_h100_energy_gv_black.jpg" title="Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия" alt="Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-product__info-cell">
                            <div class="x-order-product__title-holder">
                                <a class="x-order-product__title" data-qaid="product_name" href="https://odessa.prom.ua/p695677474-azimut-energy-besplatnaya.html" target="_blank">Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="x-order-product__data">
                                <div>
                                    <!-- react-text: 110 -->Цена:
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                    <span class="x-order-product__price" data-qaid="product_price">2&nbsp;886 грн.
                                                </span>
                                </div>
                                <div data-qaid="quantity_field">
                                    <!-- react-text: 113 -->Количество:
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                    <!-- react-text: 114 -->1
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                    <!-- react-text: 115 -->шт.
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="x-order-product__presence">
                                    <!-- react-text: 117 -->Наличие:
                                    <!-- /react-text --><span>В наличии</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-prepare__total">
                    <div class="x-order-total">
                        <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_save x-hidden"><span class="x-order-total__value"></span></div>
                        <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_total">
                            <div class="x-order-total__label">Всего</div>
                            <div class="x-order-total__value"><span data-qaid="total_price">2 886 грн.</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-prepare__delivery">
                    <div class="x-order-delivery">
                        <div class="x-order-delivery__text-column">
                            <!-- react-text: 131 -->Стоимость доставки
                            <!-- /react-text -->
                            <div class="x-order-delivery__text"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-delivery__value-column"><span data-qaid="delivery_price"><!-- react-text: 135 -->Уточняйте у продавца<!-- /react-text --></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/js/checkout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78217/discussion-on-answer-by-coffee-kyiv-----).